# Groovy read yaml file returns array

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, snakeyaml

yml_1:

```
server
  port: 1023
```

yml_2:

```
server
  port: 4001
```

I use `readYaml` in Jenkins to read the YAML file:

```
void checkService(waitTime) {
    def conf = readYaml file: "./${CURRENT_STAGE}/src/main/resources/${CONF_NAME}"
    String port = conf.server.port.toString()

    timeout(waitTime) {
        waitUntil {
           script {
             def r = sh script: "wget -q http://${HOST_NAME}:${port}/info -O /dev/null", returnStatus: true
             return (r == 0)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine in first yml, the url returns http://hostname:1023/info,
but it returns array if calls checkService() again for second yml file: http://hostname:[4001]/info

Where is the problem?

Comment: Try reading the 2nd file first and see if the issue happens ...if it doesn't then your 2nd yaml file is written wrong maybe a comma or extra space ?

Comment: your yaml files are not valid. after `server` there  must be a `:`

Comment: @daggett That's a typo, my yml is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this solved

```
def conf = readYaml file: "${CONF_NAME}"
String port = ""
if ( conf.server.port instanceof Integer ) {
    port = conf.server.port
}
if ( conf.server.port instanceof ArrayList ) {
    port = conf.server.port[0]
}
```